# A name for a template-matching parameter

Tags: language-agnostic, parameters, computer-vision, template-matching

In my template-matching code I need the user to pass a floating-point parameter, which specifies whether the algorithm should concentrate only on the best matches (thus work faster) or analyse even low-probability areas (making it slower).

The parameter is linear and normalized such that possible values are in range <0, 1>. It doesn't matter whether the number of resulting matches increases or decreases as the parameter grows, as this can be easily changed. The default value is around 0.5; when the value is on one end of the range, the algorithm should possibly return only one match (and work fast); whereas the other end should mean lots of possible matches and long processing time.

What name should I choose for this parameter such that it makes sense to the end-user? I've been thinking about MatchingQuality or MatchingDepth but neither seems appropriate and self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably call it `matchingAccuracy`, `matchingPrecision` or something like that.

Comment: "Precision" looks like it describes how well the template fits, not how many worse-matching positions were found, I like "accuracy" more.

Answer (score 0):

How about MatchThresholdCoefficient?

Comment: Even though I do use the "threshold" word somewhere in the code, I think I should not expose such name to a user of a computer-vision application, where it is kind of reserved for the threshold operator.